# Replacing for loops with map method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, dictionary, refactoring

I have this code that is working...

```js
var allSummaries = [ {id: "1", name: "Example1"},  {id: "2", name: "Example2"}, {id: "3", name: "Example3"}, {id: "4", name: "Example4"},  {id: "5", name: "Example5"}, {id: "6", name: "Example6"}, {id: "7", name: "Example7"}, {id: "8", name: "Example8"}, {id: "9", name: "Example9"}, {id: "10", name: "Example10"}, ];

var uniqueSummaries = ["4","6","9"];

function extractSpecificSummaries(arr1, arr2) {
   var summariesBasedOnIDs = [];
   for (var i = 0; i <= arr1.length - 1; i++) {
      for (var x = 0; x <= arr2.length -1; x++) {
         if (arr1[i].id == arr2[x]) {
           summariesBasedOnIDs.push(arr1[i]);

         }

      }
   }
   return summariesBasedOnIDs;
}


var summaries = extractSpecificSummaries(allSummaries, uniqueSummaries);
```

But I want to make it look better by replacing the for loops with the map method. I know there is a simpler way to refactor this code. Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need `filter` not `map` - e.g. `const extractSpecificSummaries = (arr1, arr2) => arr1.filter(({id}) => arr2.includes(id));`

Comment: p.s. your "code snippet" is invalid, does not "execute" (code is fine, you just put javascript in the html block - fixed now)

Answer (score 3):

I would use a combination of [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) Array.prototype methods:

```
const result = allSummaries.filter(i => uniqueSummaries.some(u => u === i.id));

console.log(result); // [{id: "4", name: "Example4"}, {id: "6", name: "Example6"}, {id: "9", name: "Example9"}]
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you refactor that to ES5 for me please?

Answer (score 0):

I would make a fairly generic `extract` function for this:

```
const extract = (objs, keys) => objs.filter(obj => keys.some(key => obj.id === key))
extract(allSummaries, uniqueSummaries) //=> [{id: '4', name: 'Example4'}, {id: '6',... ]
```

The only reasonable way I can see to further generalize this would be if we allowed a function on `obj` and `key` rather than simply testing `id`.

Comment: Beat to it.  But mine's enough different from the answer of @dhilt that I will keep it here.